# How to remove write protection from MicroSD

Tags: software, sdcard

I have a Polaroid XS100i, I've only used it once and taken junk photos\movies to test it.  Now I'd like to delete those files but the MicroSD is write protected.

I have tried connecting via USB to the camera, inserting the MicroSD into a card reader and deleting and using a regular SD adapter (one with a write protect switch) and inserting that into a card reader.

I've also tried using `diskpart` to remove protection.

What else can I do?

Comment: How much searching have you done to find a solution?

Comment: Just enough, answer [below](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/53260/31594).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out to be a setting in the `Registry`, look at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies
```

If there is a value `WriteProtect`, set it to `0`, if not, create it as a `DWORD` and set it to `0`

Solution found at [kioskea.net](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4214-remove-write-protection-from-a-usb-key-via-the-registry)

Answer (score -1):

There is a tiny switch on the card itself. Move it to the opposite position.

Comment: I don't think his card has a write-protect switch, since he mentions trying an adapter that did have one.

Comment: MicroSD cards have no switch.

Comment: Aye, no switch on a MicroSD, only one on an adapter for a regular SD.